# Phonegap build - iframe wont show

Tags: phonegap-build

Even after trying many things in config.xml, Phonegap build and iframe does not display in the latest version of iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" />
<access origin="*"/>
```

In your config.xml file.